# Разница во времени между двумя объектами Date/time Edit

Tags: pyqt5, datetime, pyside2, pyside6, pyqt6

Не могу найти хороший пример, как можно с помощью PyQt рассчитать разницу во времени между двумя объектами `QDateTimeEdit`

С помощью `.dateTime` можно вытащить из объектов `QDateTimeEdit` по кортежу.

Есть ли простой способ получить `int` разницу (в минутах, часах итд) между двумя объектами (или хотя бы кортежами), не городя трёхэтажных структур?

Находил примеры расчёта разницы между текущим и временем, указанным в объекте `QDateTimeEdit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы не трехэтажно (хм... одноэтажно, с логичной и законной пристройкой):

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QDateTime, QTime, QDate

#from PySide6.QtCore import QDateTime, QTime, QDate
#from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime, QTime, QDate

dateTime1 = dateTimeEdit1.dateTime()
dateTime2 = dateTimeEdit2.dateTime()

# Получение разницы в количестве миллисекунд
dmsec = dateTime1.msecsTo(dateTime2)

# Из полученной разницы формируем объект QDateTime,
# из которого берем QTime, откуда берем часы и минуты
t = QDateTime(QDate(1,1,1), QTime(0, 0)).addMSecs(dmsec).time()

print(f"h: {t.hour()} m: {t.minute()}")
```

Comment: .msecsTo - это то, что мне было нужно)
QDateTime не срабатывает, возможно потому что использую Pyside?

Однако для моих задач в принципе хватит первых трёх строк. Спасибо

Comment: @Rdk в смысле не срабатывает? Импортировать не забыли? ) Сейчас добавлю